# Link Extractor in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I finally managed to get a working script.
Only 1 small issue. I can crawl all pages and get all the needed info, except from the first page.

Where is my error?

```
import scrapy.selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Prijsvergelijking.items import PrijsvergelijkingItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "coolblue"
    allowed_domains = ["tvstore.be"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.tvstore.be/category/192945/televisies.html"]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="pagination next secondary"]',)), callback = "parse_items",follow = True),)    
    def parse_items(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//li[@class='product-list-columns--item product-list-item']")
        for product in products:
            item = PrijsvergelijkingItem()
            item["Product_ref"] = product.xpath(".//h2/a/text()").extract_first().strip()
            item["Product_price"] = product.xpath(".//strong[1]/text()").extract_first().strip().replace(",",".").replace("-","")
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look hard enough.

I found the answer. All I had to do was change parse_Items to parse_start_url.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import scrapy.selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Prijsvergelijking.items import PrijsvergelijkingItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "msh"
    allowed_domains = ["mediamarkt.be"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mediamarkt.be/mcs/productlist/_TV,98952,452540.html?langId=-17&searchParams=&sort=&view=&page=1"]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="pagination-next"]',)), callback = "parse_start_url",follow = True),)    
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//ul[@class='products-list']/li/div")
        for product in products:    
            item = PrijsvergelijkingItem()
            item["Product_price"] = product.xpath('.//aside/div/div/div/text()').extract_first().replace(",", ".").replace("-", "")
            item["Product_ref"] = product.xpath('.//div/h2/a/text()').extract_first().strip()
            yield item
```